# How to get two values from two different join paths?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

**My bad, it didn't work becouse one of the tables wasn't loaded, IT WORKS...**

I'm looking to create a table for a report with only two values from two different join paths and I dont know how to do it, the following its an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
+--------------------+
|        Table1      |
+--------+-----+-----+
| idA    | idB | idC |
+--------+-----+-----+

+--------------------+
|        Table2      |
+--------+-----+-----+
| idA    | idB | idD |
+--------+-----+-----+

+--------------------+
|        Table3      |
+----------+---------+
| idD      | value1  |
+----------+---------+

+--------------------+
|        Table4      |
+----------+---------+
| idC      |   idE   |
+----------+---------+

+--------------------+
|        Table5      |
+----------+---------+
| idE      | value2  |
+----------+---------+
```

I need the two values, value1 and value2

I have try with this:

```
SELECT Table3.value1, Table5.value2
  FROM Table1
  INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.idA = Table2.idB
  AND Table1.idB = Table2.idB  
  INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.idD = Table3.idD
  INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.idC = Table4.idC
  INNER JOIN Table5 ON Table4.idE = Table5.idE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  Table3.value1, Table5.value2
FROM 
  Table1
JOIN 
  Table2 
ON 
  Table1.idB = Table2.idB
JOIN
  Table3
ON
  Table2.idD  = Table3.idD
JOIN 
  Table4
ON 
  Table1.idC = Table4.idC
JOIN
  Table5
ON
  Table4.idE = Table5.idE
-- WHERE
-- Table1.idA = [whatever]  -- hardly suggest to filter your query
```

I hardly suggest at the end that you filter your data. This answer is `DB Schema Agnostic`, meaning that I'm not sure how your schema work, but the query is `COUNTING` on having at least a matching row across all the tables. If that is not the case, you may need to use `left outer` joins and add some `null checking`. The concept will be pretty much the same, I call this `dragging` the ids all the way to where they are required :). Hope this make sense. I also hardly recommend you to get more documentation on `SQL JOIN`. Hope this helps.

Comment: My bad, it didn't work becouse one of the tables wasn't loaded, IT WORKS... Thanks for the answer David Espino!

Comment: If the answer was correct... would you mind a vote up @rodixxi? :D thanks a lot